# Updating a record on another table that corresponds to the same record

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to update a record on another table.  So I have my first table `InfoDetailsTable` that has a bunch of records with one of the values being `KitNumber`.  In this `InfoDetailsTable` table I am updating some checkboxes, and when they change it is supposed to update the `Reason` value of my table, `InfoTable`.  I'm just not quite sure how to work my UPDATE statement so that I can update my specific `InfoTable` record based on the record I changed in `InfoDetailsTable`.  Here is the code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE InfoTable SET Reason = 'blah' WHERE KitNumber = " & InfoDetailsTable.KitNumber
```

So `InfoTable` has `Reason` and `KitNumber` while `InfoDetails` also has `KitNumber` because they are in a relationship where the `KitNumber` on `InfoTable` is the primary key.  If anyone could help that would be great.  Thank you

EDIT:  Here is some more code to maybe help.

```
If USBCheck = True And ThreewayCheck = True And Car1Check = True And Car2Check = True Then
 CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE InfoTable SET Reason = '' WHERE KitNumber = " & InfoDetailsTable.KitNumber
ElseIf USBCheck = False Or ThreewayCheck = False Or Car1Check = False Or Car2Check = False Then
 CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE InfoTable SET Reason = 'blah' WHERE KitNumber = " & InfoDetailsTable.KitNumber
End If

Forms!Search!Info.Form.Requery
```

If I edit the code like `CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE InfoTable SET Reason = 'blah' "` then I get everything to work out fine, just that 'blah' in now updated to every record, where I only want it in the record I updated in `InfoDetailsTable`

Comment: Where are you trying to run this code? are you trying to update it while updating records from a form?

Comment: @ObieMD5 I have a form with 3 subforms on it.  This code is in a subform and is trying to update another subform.  I am clicking checkboxes on this form, and want it to update another subform when this happens

Comment: @patrick if your subform checkboxes are unbound and just used to build your update statement (which is what it seems like since you're building an update query), you'll need to provide us with a lot more information

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what your `InfoDetailsTable.Kitnumber` is referencing in the context of your code snippet. Usually that would be a control. Is your parent form called `InfoDetailstable` and does it include the `kitnumber` field in the recordsource?

Comment: @Patrick are all three subforms bounded by a recordsource?

Comment: @Scotch My checkboxes are part of the table.  So when I created this form, I added the subform and linked it to the table. So they are seperate.  I will edit my post to show more code.

Comment: @ObieMD5 I am not sure what you mean by that.  All 3 of the subforms were added seperately, but the primary key is `KitNumber` in `InfoTable` and is in a relationship with `KitNumber` in `InfoDetailsTable`

Comment: @Patrick I am just having a hard time trying to visualize what you have set up in my mind. So you are saying you change a checkbox on InfoTable and you want that update to be set in InfoDetailsTable?

Comment: @ObieMD5 Sorry about that.  It is actaully pretty simple to see on my end but I completely understand that it is hard for you because I am pretty new to Access.  What I am doing is changing the checkboxes `InfoDetailsTable`.  When they are changed, it will then update the field `Reason` in `InfoTable`.  So I am updating a record in `InfoTable` based on the record I changed in `InfoDetailsTable`.  I'd be happy to link a dropbox if you need a visual.

Comment: @ObieMD5 When I use this line of code `CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE InfoTable SET Reason = 'blah' "`. I get no errors at all.  But this line will update all the records of the `InfoTable` even when I only change one record in `InfoDetailsTable`.  So I just need to figure out how to update one record, based on a corresponding different record.

Comment: That should be fine but I will not be able to look at it at least for an hour, as my work blocks downloads.  Edit your question and add a link to download it and I'll get to it when I get home.

Comment: @ObieMD5 Thanks a lot.  I will edit that and keep you updated.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get from fields:

```
CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE InfoTable SET Reason = 'blah' WHERE KitNumber = " & Me.KitNumber
```

When you are working with code from the current form, you need to reference it with Me.  If it does not work still provide you link and I will look at it.

Comment: Yes! Thank you.  I have no idea why I thought I needed it to be `InfoDetailsTable.KitNumber`.  Thank you so much.  I promise I am not that slow normally.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If KitNumber is the identifying field for InfoTable (Primary Key), then what you have will work.

Comment: It gives me the error saying "Object required" and then highlights the code I submitted above.